# Проблема с подключением второй БД

Tags: java, android, база-данных, sqlite

У меня была одна БД, потом пришлось создать еще одну для других целей. После создания поменял `DATEBASE_VERSION`, но все ровно ошибка:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.fedia.regestration, PID: 2593
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Contact already exists (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Contact ( Name TEXT, Color TEXT, Price TEXT)
    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table ContactFruit already exists (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE ContactFruit ( Name TEXT, Color TEXT, Price TEXT)
```

БД 1:

```
public static final String TAG = DBHelper.class.getSimpleName();
public static final int DATEBASE_VERSION = 3;
public static final String DATEBASE_NAME = "ContactDB";
public static final String TABLE_CONTACT = "Contact";

public static final String KEY_ID = "ID";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";
public static final String KEY_LOGIN = "Login";
public static final String KEY_PASS = "Pass";
public int countUser;

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATEBASE_NAME, null, DATEBASE_VERSION);
}

public static final String CREATE_TABLE_USERS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACT + " ( "
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_LOGIN + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_PASS + " TEXT)";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USERS);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACT);

    onCreate(db);
}
```

БД 2:

```
public static final int DATEBASE_VERSION = 3;
public static final String DATEBASE_NAME_FRUIT = "FruitBD";
public static final String TABLE_CONTACT_FRUIT = "ContactFruit";

public static final String KEY_NAME_FRUIT = "Name";
public static final String KEY_COLOR = "Color";
public static final String KEY_PRICE = "Price";

public DBHelperFruit(Context context) {
    super(context, DATEBASE_NAME_FRUIT, null, DATEBASE_VERSION);
}

public static final String CREATE_TABLE_FRUIT = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACT_FRUIT + " ( "
        + KEY_NAME_FRUIT + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_COLOR + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_PRICE + " TEXT)";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_FRUIT);
    onCreate(db);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACT_FRUIT);

    onCreate(db);
}
```

В ошибке еще указано, что проблема и в этом методе:

```
@Override
public List<Fruit> getAllFruits() {
    List<Fruit> fruitList = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACT_FRUIT;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
            fruit.setName(cursor.getString(0));
            fruit.setColor(cursor.getString(1));
            fruit.setPrice(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));

            fruitList.add(fruit);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return fruitList;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Метод `onCreate(...)` вызывается при создании базы данных и служит для ее конфигурации (создания таблиц и т.п.).

У Вас этот метод выглядит следующим образом:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_FRUIT);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

В этом методе Вы создаете таблицу и зачем-то снова явно вызываете метод `onCreate(...)`, создавая рекурсию. При этом повторно выполняется запрос на создание таблицы, который и вызывает исключение:

```
SQLiteException: table ContactFruit already exists
```

так как данная таблица уже существует (была создана при первом вызове метода `onCreate(...)`).

Решить данную проблему можно убрав вызов `onCreate(db);` из метода `onCreate(...)`.